# Sending Table format report in Android email

Tags: android, html, email

I am using Android mail for sending the HTML table format report. I use the below code in my method. I have created an HTML template which I am inserting in the email. I checked my template on "https://litmus.com/tests" and it shows it can work on most of the email client. But when chooser activity started, my email table becomes plane text and then same plane text is getting sent to the email.

Do I need to change the code below or do I need to change the template itself?

**send mail method :**

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to});
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);

//for sending the message in HTML format
email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(message));

//need this to prompts email client only
email.setType("text/html");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email:"));
```